# Parse XML catch block not catching exception in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, try-catch

I have a function that takes an XML file (obtained via AJAX) as input, parses it as XML and then execute some functions on it. A stripped down version can be found below.

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./default.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        parseMech(data);
    }
});
```

**parseMech function**

```
function parseMech(xml) {
    try {
        var xmlObject = $(xml);

        // See the output function below
        $(".tree.base").html(treeBuilder(xmlObject.find("node").first()));

        console.log("succes?");
    } catch(e) {
        $("#error-msg > .the-msg").text(" Invalid XML structure").parent().fadeIn(250);
        console.log("Failed");
    }
}
```

**treeBuilder function**

```
function treeBuilder(nodes) {
    var newList = $("<ol>");

    nodes.each(function (x, e) {
        var newItem = $('<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>');

        for (var i = 0, l = e.attributes.length, a = null; i < l; i++) {
            // Don't forget to add properties as data-attributes
            a = e.attributes[i];
            newItem.attr("data-" + a.nodeName, a.value);
            if (a.nodeName == "cat" || a.nodeName == "word") {
                newItem.html('<a href="#">' + a.value + '</a>');
            }
        }
        if ($(this).children('node').length) {
            newItem.append(output($(this).children('node')));
        }
        newList.append(newItem);
    });
    return newList;
}
```

This works as it should when `default.xml` is a valid xml file. However, when it's not (for instance when I leave out a closing tag) the `catch` blok is not executed. In other words: when executing all functions with an invalid XML as source, neither console logs are executed, even though you would expect at least one (in `try` or in `catch`) to be logged.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried to add a `fail`  handler to your ajax call?

Comment: You could give a look at [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Comment: @collapsar Wouldn't that only work if ajax failed to load the fail? The XML parsing only happens `parseMech()`.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Unfortunately I need IE8 support.

Comment: @BramVanroy IE has an ActiveX Dom parser, not sure if IE8 had it http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `fail` handler in your ajax call.

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), a jquery ajax call with a dataType of xml returns a xml doc, so the data stream is being parsed in the course of the ajax call.

Alter the ajax call as follows (behaviour verified):

```
    //...
    error: function() {
        console.log("ajax failed!");
    },
    //...
```

***Note***

Consider to change the way you specify your handlers,as `error` and `success` attributes are deprecated:

```
top.$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "xml",
})
    .fail ( function() {
        console.log("ajax failed!");
    })
    .done ( function(data) {
        console.log("ajax ok!");
        parseMech(data);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! And I always wondered what the difference between `error` and fail was.